# XamarinForms ListView item fill with

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I force my TemplateItem to expand and fill the entire width of the ListView?

AS you can see in the Screenshot, the listView has a red background, and my items have an white background.

The code of the DataTemplate:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="InformationMessageTemplate">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Sender}"  />
      <Label Text=" chegou na sala" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </DataTemplate>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the StackLayout in a ViewCell:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InformationMessageTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
             <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                 <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Sender}"  />
                 <Label Text=" chegou na sala" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
             </StackLayout>
         </ViewCell.View>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but didn't worked , still the same thing =(

Comment: Hmm, that's odd - I have a similar situation and it seems to work for me - can you post the whole ListView Xaml?

Comment: Have you tried setting the padding of your layouts to 0? specifically the StackLayout and I am not sure if the ListView has a padding property but maybe even your ContentPage has a padding on the right side.

Comment: In addition to @MarioGalván's suggestion it might also be a good idea to check the Spacing property on the StackLayout. I don't think that would be the issue, but it does default to 10dpx IIRC, which looks like about what the gap is.